# Previewing rails server on AWS Cloud 9: VFS Connection does not exist [Firefox only]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, firefox, vfs, aws-cloud9

**Update: This is specific to Firefox. This does not occur using Chrome. I will leave the text below as is, but now the main question is, how and what in Firefox is causing this.** It occurs regardless of cookie settings, such as allowing third-party cookies and trackers.

---

Preface: I've searched and read dozens of pages trying to resolve this issue I've gone through all the troubleshooting steps in the AWS documentation, eg,

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html#app-preview-share

and this thread:

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=849200 as well as resources on stackoverflow

and the c9 forums

- https://community.c9.io/t/what-is-vfs-connection-does-not-exist-on-aws-c9/22697/4)

---

I am trying to preview a running rails app from the Cloud 9 IDE. When I run the app using `rails server`, there are no error messages indicating anything wrong. The output shows `Started GET '/' for [my home IP] ...... 200 Completed OK`.

Console Output:
[image: console output]

Trying to preview the running app only produces a "OOPS VFS connection does not exist" screen. The preview url is always `https://[user_generated_sequence].vfs.cloud9.[region].amazonaws.com/` All TCP traffic is allowed as per the rules set up by following the troubleshooting guides.

OOPS error message page:
[image: console output]

The same issue occurs whether using puma or WEBrick. With WEBrick, a popup for the preview link appears, but leads to the same error message page. With puma, the running app is listening on `tcp://[localhost/0.0.0.0]:[8080 or 3000]`. With WEBrick, it listens instead on `http://localhost:8080`.

I have followed the instructions exactly in the rails tutorial to set up a simple app. Everything in the code itself should be fine. How can I get this to work correctly? I'm very confused and about to give up on rails.

Comment: https://community.c9.io/t/what-is-vfs-connection-does-not-exist-on-aws-c9/22697/5

Comment: Any luck with this? something that doesn't require burning everything to your God and start fresh?

Comment: Yes, I just use Chrome for AWS now (and some other Google-connected sites that don't work correctly on FF)

Comment: Make sure your user has read access to the file, for me it was that simple.

Answer (score 7):

I recently had the same issues after updating Firefox because cross-site cookies are required to preview a running rails application. If, like me, you have disabled that in Firefox as part of strict [Enhanced Tracking Protection](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enhanced-tracking-protection-firefox-desktop), they will need to be enabled at least for this specific site.

Comment: This actually did the trick. Thank you

Comment: That should be the correct answer. Just to add: simply change Enhanced Tracking for your website from Standard to Custom and untick Cookies. That should do the trick

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are accessing the preview from the same browser:

> This URL works only when the IDE for the environment is open and the
>   application is running in the same web browser

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html#app-preview-preview-app

Answer (score 2):

Try disable Ad Blockers and privacy Extention. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Something that worked for me, do the following:
run:

```
rails s
```

the in the AWS EDE click on 'Preview' and 'Select Running Application'

Once it will open click on the button/link and it should open in another window with the running application.
[image]

Note: Doing this manually by copying the URL link and pasting in another tab did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to allow third party cookies
in chrome it's
Settings >> Security >> Cookies and web data >> Choose second option(block cookies only in incognito)

That works for me

Answer (score 1):

On cloud9, click the shield logo in the address bar and switch "Enhanced Tracking Protection" to be off. Then refresh the page and the preview.

Comment: This worked for me. Maybe because I did all of the above and yours was the last thing I needed to change, but whatever. Thanks for the reminder to refresh the preview too!

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this as well. Finally, I changed the cookie setting from all third-party cookies to cookies from unvisited sites (See image)

[Cookie Settings for Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR5vX.png)